# Spending pesos at IAH

Tags: airports, money, iah, houston

I have a layover in Houston on the way back from Mexico, and I have a small amount of money left in pesos. Will I be able to buy food with pesos in the airport, or would I have to exchange them first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Businesses at IAH (or in the United States in general, with the [exception](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/17900/2/MPRA_paper_17900.pdf) of the occasional business near the border) will not typically accept pesos. You'll need US dollars or a credit/debit card.

There are [currency exchange locations](https://www.travelex.com/stores-by-state/airport-currency-exchange/george-bush-houston-international-airport) at IAH. There are also ATMs available.

Answer (score 0):

While you can exchange MXN into USD at almost any airport, you can get a much better exchange rate in Mexico.  The best cash exchange rates are in Mexico City airport Terminal 1, where you can often find a spread as low as 1%.

Answer (score -1):

No (buy food); yes (exchange them first).